# Android Studio error: "libpng error: Not a PNG file" while adding .png file to drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio, libpng

I am getting the mentioned error as soon as I add a png file to the drawable folder:

> :app:mergeDebugResources
>   AAPT err(Facade for 2099945199): libpng error: Not a PNG file
>   FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

There is no problem with the png file. It was working in ADT. Tried with several other files too. Same result.
The problem goes away as soon as I delete the file and clean the project.
After searching a lot on the internet, I came around a work around which is adding the below lines:

I added this to the build.gradle (Module):

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
...
}
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Am I at fault or is this an Android Studio bug?

Comment: What way are you importing the png file? I'd recommend right-clicking on the drawable folder and choosing `New->Image asset` as shown in this [image](http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Click-on-drawable-resource-XML-file.jpg) Just ignore the arrow :D couldn't find a better image

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. This method is to be mainly used for icons(I think). I am looking for importing a png file for using as a background (not icons) in one of my activities. In this method, the image is getting cropped or heavily distorted, as its dimensions are large, so this method will not serve the purpose. Can you tell me your preferred way of adding background image to activity in Android Studio?

Comment: I've heard of a library called [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which is used for loading images.